# Java Switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

when I go into the sub menu, and completing e.g. case 1, after the case has been completed, it then automatically jumps to case 2 of the main menu, can anyone tell me how to stop this as i want it just to show the main menu again

```
switch (choice) {
    case 1:    //finish add passenger
        System.out.println(" 1 - Add passenger");
        System.out.println(mySubMenu.displayMenu());
        int subChoice = mySubMenu.getChoice();
        switch (subChoice) {
            case 1:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers forename");
                    String aforename = strKeyB.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers surname");
                    String surname = strKeyB.next();

                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers nationality");
                    String nationality = strKeyB.next();

                    System.out.println("Please enter the passenger age");
                    int age = intKeyB.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(pass1.pasengerAdd(aforename, surname, nationality, age));
                    break;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());

                }

            case 2:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers forename");
                    String onforename = strKeyB.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers surname");
                    String onSurname = strKeyB.next();
                    pass1.pasengerAdd(onforename, onSurname);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());

                }
                break;
            case 3:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers forename");
                    String nnforename = strKeyB.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers surname");
                    String nnSurname = strKeyB.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers age");
                    int intAge = intKeyB.nextInt();
                    pass1.pasengerAdd(nnforename, nnSurname, intAge);


                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());

                }//end catch 
                break;
            case 4:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers forename");
                    String naforename = strKeyB.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers surname");
                    String naSurname = strKeyB.next();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the passengers nationality");
                    String naNat = strKeyB.next();
                    pass1.pasengerAdd(naforename, naSurname, naNat);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex.toString());

                }
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println(myMenu.displayMenu());
                break;
        }//end sub menu switch


    case 2:
        try {
            System.out.println(" 2 - Delete Passenger");
            System.out.println("Please enter the passenger forename ");
            String dForename = strKeyB.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter the passenger surname ");
            String dSurname = strKeyB.next();
            System.out.println(pass1.passengerDelete(dForename, dSurname));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

        break;
}
```

Comment: Try to use break label for breaking outer switch statement.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Or place break after inner switch statement. What is simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` at the end of each `case` block.

Problem here is you have two `case 1:`:

- case 1: in `switch(choice)`
- case 1: in `switch(subchoice)`

You missed 2 things:

- the `break` statement in `switch(choice)`, so code of `case 2:` will be executed.
- the catch branch of `case 1:` in `switch(subchoice)`.

Look this simple case:

```
switch(choice) {
case 1:
    // code1
    break;
case 2: 
    // code2
    break;
}
```

Here case codes will be executed individually,

Otherwise in this code:

```
switch(choice) {
case 1:
    // code1
case 2: 
    // code2
}
```

When `break` is not used, code is executed continously, so when `choice==1`  `code1` **AND** `code2` will be executed. But if `choice==2` just `code2` will be executed. *This is **really** usefull when 2 or more options share some code.*

**NOTE:** this is also valid:

```
switch(choice) {
case 1:
case 2: 
    // code1
    // code2
    break;
}
```

In this statement `Case 1` and `Case 2` will execute same code.

---

## SOLUTION:

Knowing this, your code must have 2 fixes:

1. insert `break` statement in `switch(choice)` just before the code of `case 2:`
2. move the `break` statement of `case 1:` in `switch(subchoice)` to the end, just before the code of `case 2:`

```
switch (choice) {
case 1:    //finish add passenger
    System.out.println(" 1 - Add passenger");
    System.out.println(mySubMenu.displayMenu());
    int subChoice = mySubMenu.getChoice();
    switch (subChoice) {
        case 1:
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter the passengers forename");
                String aforename = strKeyB.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter the passengers surname");
                String surname = strKeyB.next();

                System.out.println("Please enter the passengers nationality");
                String nationality = strKeyB.next();

                System.out.println("Please enter the passenger age");
                int age = intKeyB.nextInt();
                System.out.println(pass1.pasengerAdd(aforename, surname, nationality, age));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());

            }
            break;  // here you miss case 1: in switch(subchoice) when exception

        case 2:
            try {
                System.out.println("Please enter the passengers forename");
                String onforename = strKeyB.next();
                System.out.println("Please enter the passengers surname");
                String onSurname = strKeyB.next();
                pass1.pasengerAdd(onforename, onSurname);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.toString());

            }
            break;

//
// more code until...
//

break; 

case 2:  // here you miss case 1: in switch(choice) 
    try {
        System.out.println(" 2 - Delete Passenger");
```